# How to make typeORM find query and realtions together

Tags: typescript, orm, typeorm

according to: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options

I and table Person in database with first_name and some relations with other tables.

I find I can do query:

```
const result = await prep.find({first_name: Like("%out%")})
```

I can also do query:

```
const result = await prep.find({relations: ['user','belong_organization']})
```

But When I query:

```
const result = await prep.find({first_name: Like("%out%"), relations: ['user','belong_organization']})
```

There will be ignore my first_name conditions, how to make query and relations today?

Answer (score 0):

```
const result = await prep.find({ where: { first_name: Like("%out%") }, relations: ['user','belong_organization'] })
```

the complete example of find options has already shown on https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/blob/master/docs/find-options.md#advanced-options
[image]